# react-redux can't find store but it sure looks like it's there

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, redux

OK - what the heck am I missing... spent a day and a half trying to solve this and am about to ditch redux...

I have the following root route...

```jsx
...

import configureStore from 'NewApp/client/store';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createBrowserHistory();
const store = configureStore(history);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
   <Router
     history={history}
     children={routes}
     {...clientOptions.props} />
  </Provider>
  , rootElement
);

...
```

And I see the store object, but I keep getting an error saying it's not there...

Adding requested additional code:

```
...

import rootReducer from '../reducers';

const middlewares = [
  thunkMiddleware,
  loggerMiddleware,
];

const finalCreateStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(history, initialState) {
  const store = finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState);
  syncReduxAndRouter(history, store, state => state.router);

  return store;
}
...
```

...

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { clearNotification } from '../actions/notifications';
import { logout } from '../actions/auth';
import App from '../components/App';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    locale: state.app.locale,
    loggingIn: state.auth.loggingIn,
    messages: state.app.messages,
    notification: state.notification,
    title: state.app.title,
    user: state.auth.user,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    clearNotification,
    logout,
  }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

[image]

Comment: Did you import `Provider` from `react-redux`?

Comment: Yes I did... I just left the other imports out for brevity above and without that I would get a hard failure ;-)

Comment: Can you show the code where you use `connect`?

Comment: I updated the question with the connect and additional info

Comment: I have never seen `react-router` used in that way. Can you try just putting the container `<App/>` inside of `<Provider>` and see if it works?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, I figured out the root issue. But on the router comment... [this](https://github.com/jlongster/redux-simple-router) extension details that approach pretty much verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's the deal... it turns out that the demo app I am using code splits and if you add flux/redux into the mix in additional to all the 'joy' redux has already given, you actually need to 'split' your reducers as well per [this repo](https://github.com/insin/react-examples/tree/master/code-splitting-redux-reducers).

The original error in my question above happened going to any non-root route because webpack code splitting makes those router calls async - basically getting things out of kilter with the reducer(s) in the store. The [repo](https://github.com/insin/react-examples/tree/master/code-splitting-redux-reducers) linked to in this answer shows how to keep the router and store in sync with the 'dynamic' reducers.

Am I the only one starting to feel like adding in redux is becoming more work than writing an entire large, complex app in the first place? Seeing those redux 10 line 'counter' app demos made it look so... easy? Anyway, hopefully this unveiling which by the way is not well documented in redux yet can help someone in the future!